# Counting number of orders depending on city

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table that is being created, we will say that column 1 is an order_id, and column 2 is user_id, column 3 is start_date, column 4 is end_date and column 5 is city.

```
order_id  user_id Start_date   end_date     city
101       1       200001       200101       X
101       2       200101       200110       y
101       3       200110       200112       z
101       3       200112       200210       z
```

I want to count by city the number of order_ids that moved out of it to another city and in another column the number of order_ids that moved into it from another city.

I would like it to come out as a table, like this:

```
city moved_out_orders moved_into_orders
x    1                0
y    1                1
z    0                1
```

Comment: "moved out of it to another city" is based on start_date or end_date or both? How exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
with
x as (
  select a.city as from_city, b.city as to_city
  from t a
  join t b on a.order_id = b.order_id 
          and a.city <> b.city
          and a.end_date = b.start_date
),
o (city, cnt) as (
  select from_city, count(*) from x group by from_city
),
i (city, cnt) as (
  select to_city, count(*) from x group by to_city
)
select
  coalesce(i.city, o.city) as city,
  o.cnt as moved_out_orders,
  i.cnt as moved_in_orders
from i
full join o on o.city = i.city
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you just want to enumerate the rows for each order and then discard the highest and lowest for each count:

```
select city,
       sum(case when seqnum_desc > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as moved_out,
       sum(case when seqnum_asc > 1 then 1 else 0 end) as moved_in
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by startdate) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by startdate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
group by city;
```

EDIT:

You appear to have adjacent rows in the same city.  Seems strange, but instead you can use `lead()` and `lag()`:

```
select city,
       sum(case when next_city <> city then 1 else 0 end) as moved_out,
       sum(case when prev_city <> city then 1 else 0 end) as moved_in
from (select t.*,
             lag(city) over (partition by orderid order by startdate) as prev_city,
             lead(city) over (partition by orderid order by startdate) as next_city
      from t
     ) t
group by city;
```

Comment: You are missing one desc. And have swapped the in and out. But the biggest problem imho is, that you count moves from one city to the very same city.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek . . . Good catch that the cities sometimes don't change.  That is a good read to use `lag()` and `lead()` instead.